# Calculate Percentage Column for List of Dataframes When Total Value is Hidden Within the Rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
```

I feel like there is a simple solution for this but I'm stuck. The code below creates a simple list of two dataframes (they are the same for simplicity of the example, but the real data has different values)

```
Loc<-c("Montreal","Toronto","Vancouver","Quebec","Ottawa","Hamilton","Total")
Count<-c("2344","2322","122","45","4544","44","9421")

Data<-data_frame(Loc,Count)
Data2<-data_frame(Loc,Count)
Data3<-list(Data,Data2)
```

Each dataframe has "Total" within the "Loc" column with the corresponding overall total of the "Count" column. I would like to calculate percentages for each dataframe by dividing each value in the "Count" column by the total, which is the last number in the "Count" column.

I would like the percentages to be added as new columns for each dataframe.

For this example, the total is the last number in the column, but in reality, it may be mixed anywhere in the column and can be found by the corresponding "Total" value in the "Loc" column.

I would like to use purrr and Tidyverse:

Below is an example of the code, but I'm stuck on the percentage...

```
Data3%>%map(~mutate(.x,paste0(round(100*  (MISSING PERCENTAGE),2),"%"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses only base-R:

```
for (i in seq_along(Data3)) {
  Data3[[i]]$Count <- as.numeric(Data3[[i]]$Count)
  n <- nrow(Data3[[i]])
  Data3[[i]]$perc <- Data3[[i]]$Count / Data3[[i]]$Count[n]
} 

> Data3
[[1]]
# A tibble: 7 x 3
        Loc Count        perc
      <chr> <dbl>       <dbl>
1  Montreal  2344 0.248805859
2   Toronto  2322 0.246470651
3 Vancouver   122 0.012949793
4    Quebec    45 0.004776563
5    Ottawa  4544 0.482326717
6  Hamilton    44 0.004670417
7     Total  9421 1.000000000

[[2]]
# A tibble: 7 x 3
        Loc Count        perc
      <chr> <dbl>       <dbl>
1  Montreal  2344 0.248805859
2   Toronto  2322 0.246470651
3 Vancouver   122 0.012949793
4    Quebec    45 0.004776563
5    Ottawa  4544 0.482326717
6  Hamilton    44 0.004670417
7     Total  9421 1.000000000
```

Comment: Thanks, but are you able to provide an answer that doesn't use a for loop? (Apply family of functions). Or even better, a Tidyverse solution that uses pipes (%>%)? I'm only asking because this question is actually part of a larger chunk of code that is primarily in Tidyverse syntax and which uses pipes so suddenly switching to a for loop will cause me to change the flow. Hopefully you can help?

Comment: not very familiar with Tidyverse... can maybe look into that in few days if noone has provided a satisfying answer

Comment: No problem. Are you able to rewrite using lapply (or similar apply group of functions) in place of the for loop?

Comment: I accepted your answer since it works for what I generally need. But I asked another question about rewriting it in Tidyverse syntax so if you figure it out you can get another credit.